# Objective-C class method with generic parameter cannot be called in Swift

Tags: objective-c, generics, compiler-errors, swift3, class-method

I have a method that is declared as follows in Objective-C

```
+(void) clearAll:(NSArray<ParameterType> *)values;
```

I have another class method that is declared as follows, in another object

```
+(NSArray *) values;
```

I am trying to call these from Swift as follows:

```
MyObject.clearAll(MyOtherObject.values())
```

It displays an array of different compile-time errors when I try to run it.

The errors are:

```
"Generic parameter 'ObjectType' could not be inferred"
```

then I try `MyObject.clearAll(MyOtherObject.values() as NSArray<MyOtherObject>)`

and get `"Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSArray'"`

When I try MyObject.clearAll(MyOtherObject.values() as! Array)

I get `"Array<MyOtherObject> is not convertible to [Any]"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler errors are exceedingly unhelpful in this situation; they point pretty much everywhere except the right place. The problem is because of the generic parameter on `MyObject`: in Swift, an unspecialized generic type is not a thing unto itself, and methods can't be called on it. It has to be specialized to become concrete.

The resolution is simple: just add the type argument:

```
MyObject<MyOtherObject>.clearAll(MyOtherObject.values())
```

(You'll need to do the same for `MyOtherObject` if it's generic too.)